# Have ImageListItem Img take up all of Card Space?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, react-component

I'm ultimately trying to have an ImageListItem take up all available space inside of a card. (I want a rounded Card with an image background with a text bar at the bottom). I cannot get the ImageListItem to take up any more than the image's height. I want to stretch the image and bar to take up all space in the card.

`MyComponent`

```
<Card key={item.name} sx={{ width: 'auto', height: 'auto', aspectRatio: '1 / 1' }}>
    <CardContent sx={{ padding: 0, maxHeight: '100%' }}>
        <ImageListItem sx={{ maxHeight: '100%', padding: 0 }}>
            <img
                src={`${item.img}?w=248&fit=crop&auto=format`}
                srcSet={`${item.img}?w=248&fit=crop&auto=format&dpr=2 2x`}
                alt={item.name}
                loading="lazy"
            />
            <ImageListItemBar title={item.name} subtitle={item.sciName} />
         </ImageListItem>
     </CardContent>
 </Card>
```

[Card with ImageListItem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEH5u.png)

[Expected Card fills in the blue area with the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBjcD.png)

I've tried throwing `minHeight=100%` `height=100%` and other attributes everywhere with no luck..

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

try this and add a margin and padding for image.and to add rounded corners you can simply add css attribute"border-radius: 5px;".

Comment: This perhaps gets me halfway there, but obviously I lose out on all the styling provided by the `ImageListItem` and `Card` components. Is there any way to get those components to work with what I am trying to do? Thanks

Comment: can you add a sample image or draft what you want

Comment: There is an image already listed, but I added another with a blue coloring to show the area that should be filled in with the image and subtitle box.